# Uploading image from React-Native app to Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

In React-Native app how can i upload an image from user' device to Firebase storage? I'm doing like:

```
var file = {
   uri: 'file:///Users/...../LONG_PATH/....../Documents/images/name.jpg'
}

var storageRef = this.firebase.storage().ref();
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file);
```

But it throws an error:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>
> Firebase Storage:
>   Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Can't find variable: Blob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html), software engineer said:

> React Native does not support the File and Blob types, so Firebase Storage uploads will not work in this environment. File downloads do work however.

But I found this [module](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) wich can transform file to blob types. Maibe can help in your solution

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Am I correct in saying that because this [lib polyfills Blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/44) that the OP's example code should work as-is?

Comment: **Update** this is a native method on `fetch`. I currently am using something similar after uploading files in React Native.


      `const photoData = await fetch(imageUri)
      const blob = await photoData.blob()
      return blob`

Answer (score 4):

I found this, hopefully this helps. [Functional React-Native with Firebase storage Example](https://github.com/wkh237/rn-firebase-storage-upload-sample)